How to install Windows 10 on NVMe on old PC without BIOS modification and without not removable external USB drive?
The internal AHCI SATA drive has the active partition. Windows 10 is installed on it. Is it possible to use this for installing and subsequently running Windows 10 from the NVMe drive? Is it possible to use the bootloader of the installed Windows 10 on the internal AHCI SATA drive to running Windows 10 from the NVMe drive?
Or what needs to be installed on an internal AHCI SATA drive to boot Windows 10 from the NVMe drive?
Or is it impossible to do this without a bootable external not removable USB drive? Single-use of the external USB drive is allowed during the OS installation.
It is assumed that the NVMe drive is connected to the motherboard via an PCIe to M.2 adapter without additional chips. The BIOS of chipsets H55 P55 H57 Q57 are not modificable for NVMe.

If the motherboard doesn't support PCIe NVMe devices.  What is your plan to add that support? You will not be happy with the performance running Windows from a removable device connected to the system through USB.  There is a reason Microsoft dropped support for Windows 2 Go over 5 years ago.

Your motherboard doesn't support NVMe drives. How are you intending to use it? If with an adapter - arguably it won't be much better than a SATA drive, if at all - you'll need to keep the SATA drive for the ESP (EFI System Partition).

How is the NVMe drive connected to the motherboard? PCIe to M.2 adapter? With or without Boot-Bios on the adapter? Is it an M.2 Sata drive or a real M2 NVMe drive? Is it something else?  Please EDIT your question and add that information. Currently it risks being closed for being unclear.

A clarification about the connection has been added. I expect that PCIe 2.0 x4 has a speed 3...4 times greater than SATA III. The internal AHCI SATA drive remains connected. This is stated in the question. An extra quarter-minute of OS boot time doesn't matter.

if you have a proper windows 10 ISO file, you can install windows to a secondary drive without needing bootable external media. You'd partition the new drive, mount the ISO, and run a series of commands involving the tool dism, use bootsect to mark bootable, turn off pc, remove the old windows drive and boot with the new one. This is a duplicate question, but I cannot find the proper old post. You might dig something up with dism /Apply-Image /ImageFile as a search term.

@Yorik The old PC seems to be BIOS and it won't boot from any additional drive in the PCIe to M.2 adapter. It may work by keeping at least one native SATA drive to store the bootloader in the MBR and BIOS set to boot from that drive and present during Windows installation so the installer install the bootloader in it. The system partitions can then reside even in a drive that isn't bootable by the firmware.
